# How to keep selected the button on click of another button on same page using bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, bootstrap-4

On click of one of blue buttons(only one can be selected at a time) it is selected. But when I click on `Buy` button the previous blue button gets unselected. Therefore, I cannot read the value of blue button by `onclick` of yellow button.

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pro8bhu1/vteaLc32/).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Sign in Success</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="btn-group" style="background:black;width:100%">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Tr</button>
        <div style="width:10px"></div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">T</button>
        <div style="width:10px"></div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Vt</button>
        <div style="width:10px"></div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Rt</button>
    </div>
    <br> <br>
    <h2 style="text-decoration:underline;" align="center">T</h2>
    <div align="center"><!-- id="centerit" -->
        <br> <br> <br>
        <!-- <div style="width:50px"></div> -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary cust" value="bu">Butter</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary cust" value="mi">Milk</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary cust" value="bi">Biscuit</button>
        <br> <br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value = "submit">Buy!</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the `blue button` to remain selected when i click on `buy button` which is not happening now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding radio buttons instead of buttons

That is what you required

```
<div id="radioBtn" class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm active" data-toggle="fun" data-title="bu">Butter</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm notActive" data-toggle="fun" data-title="mi">Milk</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm notActive" data-toggle="fun" data-title="bi">Biscuit</a>
</div>

<script>
    $('#radioBtn a').on('click', function(){
    var sel = $(this).data('title');
    var tog = $(this).data('toggle');
    $('#'+tog).prop('value', sel);

    $('a[data-toggle="'+tog+'"]').not('[data-title="'+sel+'"]').removeClass('active').addClass('notActive');
    $('a[data-toggle="'+tog+'"][data-title="'+sel+'"]').removeClass('notActive').addClass('active');
})
</script>

<style>
#radioBtn .notActive{
    color: #3276b1;
    background-color: #fff;
}
</style>
```

Here is an updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yvwxkse9/)

Comment: Thank you. With this can I pass the selected "blue" button value to next page on click of `Buy` ?

Comment: Yes, you can get data-title value of attribute using `active` class.

Comment: ok and using normal buttons(like I was trying) it's not possible, right ?

Comment: You can set active or inactive button css and conditions but it will take longer code and lengthy conditions to achieve your requirement.

Comment: great then I shall try with this approach itself . thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can put your buttons in a form and replace the three blue buttons with radio buttons. See the documentation here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0wj1m8ce/

```
 <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle"  data-toggle="buttons" >
      <label class="btn btn-primary cust">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" value="bu"> Butter
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary cust">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off" value="mi"> Milk
      </label>
      <label  class="btn btn-primary cust">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off" value="bi" > Biscuit
      </label>
    </div>
```